# Getting feedback and suggestions from users

Tags: user-feedback

I am rebuilding an ERP software.I want to get feedback and suggestions from users on the current software , so that I can build more user-friendly interface and functionality.Suggest me some ideas how to get ideas and feedback from them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't beat sitting in a room with the user, watching how they carry out tasks with the software and asking questions. This is the most basic, low-tec version of *Usability Testing* that there is, but I find it the most informative.

Do it with as many different users as possible (large sample size), using a list of tasks that cover all the functionality that you want to test. Watch for the following things:

- **Are some tasks needlessly complicated to complete?** Actions that are commmonly repeated should be as streamlined as possible.
- **Is there anything in the UI that the user finds confusing?** Make a note of why.
- **What frustrates the user?** Make sure you get to the bottom of this by asking more questions.
- **What does the user like?** It is important to take note of this so you don't accidently interfere with elements that work well for the user while fixing other usability issues.
- **Anything strange?** Make a note of anything that strikes you as strange during the test. Perhaps the user is using a feature in an unanticipated way?

Users familiar with the existing software will definitely have wish lists. They are just waiting for someone to ask them (perhaps they already asked for things a long time ago but gave up asking).